# Tools for Building an OCA (Occasionally Connected Application) 2015

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce, sql-server-2014-express, occasionallyconnected

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103918/tools-for-building-an-oca-occasionally-connected-application), but the times and technology seemed to have dramatically changed, so I find the need to ask again.

The changes being:
* Compact 3.5 SP2 is deprecated (soon to be no support)
* Compact 4.0 does not support replication/sync (yes there is a work-around, but that is not sufficient for enterprise solution)

For building a new application on the .NET stack, what technology should be used for the local database for an occasionally connected application.

The client platform will be a windows tablet (with windows 8.1/10 Professional).  The server is current SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

We're leaning towards just using SQL Server 2014 Express for the client db since Compact Edition seems sunset altogether.  Also - using merge replication between client/local db and server db.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use Merge Replication between SQL Server Express and SQL Server 2014.

Or you could use RDA with SQL Server CE 4.0, basically as described here:

[http://www.amazon.com/Keeping-Windows-Tablets-Sync-Server-ebook/dp/B00D9YDKLU/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D9YDKLU)

(The book uses 3.5 SP2, but 4.0 works fine as well: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/03/snapshot-synchronization-with-sql.html )

Comment: Thank you for the response Erik.  The problem is that RDA is being deprecated.  I want a long term solution.

Comment: I guess we could just manually pull down the lookup tables and manually post the transactions from the tablet to the server...

Comment: Also, why the hate from MSFT on getting rid of CE and sync/repl?

Comment: Are there any "long term" solutions these days? - SQLCE will be supported until 2021!

Comment: I love your cheery enthusiasm brother.